# How to delete a view from parent layout to get a bitmap excluding a view?

Tags: android, image, view, bitmap, imageview

I have one screen on which I have an image view, the text on the image view and one layout which I have included in the same for like and share functions.

Now I wnat to save the image which is set to the image view and the text which is set on the image. For that I have the code to convert the view to bitmap.

But in the converted bitmap I can see the icluded layout too. I want to exclude that layout and save the bitmap. Can it be possible?

Fragment :(Image view and text To be saved as an image)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                                                   android:id = "@+id/container"
                                                   tools:context = ".Fragments.QuotesFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView_theme"
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"
        android:visibility = "visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent">

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/textView_quotes"
            android:layout_width = "250dp"
            android:layout_height = "300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
            android:autoSizeTextType = "uniform"
            android:fontFamily = "@font/open_sans_semibold_italic"
            android:gravity = "start|center_vertical"
            android:text = "Doing a same thing over and over again and expecting different results"
            android:textAlignment = "textStart"
            android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
            android:textSize = "@dimen/text_size24" />

        <include
            android:id = "@+id/include2"
            layout = "@layout/share_save_like_layout"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "60dp"
            android:layout_below = "@id/textView_quotes"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
            android:layout_marginTop = "@dimen/margin_20"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Included layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height = "60dp"
                                                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
                                                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView_favourite"
        android:layout_width = "30dp"
        android:layout_height = "30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart = "@dimen/margin_80"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "@dimen/margin_80"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight = "60dp"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_favourite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "@id/imageView_collection"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView_collection"
        android:layout_width = "30dp"
        android:layout_height = "30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight = "60dp"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_bookmark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "@id/imageView_share"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "@id/imageView_favourite"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/imageView_share"
        android:layout_width = "30dp"
        android:layout_height = "30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "@dimen/margin_80"
        android:layout_marginRight = "@dimen/margin_80"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_share"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "@id/imageView_collection"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To create a bitmap :

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    ;
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag") public static File createShareImage(View relativeLayout)
{

    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(relativeLayout);
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"folderName");
    if (!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(dir, "capture.jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ExpressionEditImageActivity", "Error, " + e);
    }

    return file;
}
```

Can I remove the included layout and get the bitmap?